# Querying a DynamoDb table using a combination of `begins_with` and `between` conditions

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

How can I query a DynamoDb table using a combination of the `BETWEEN` and `BEGINS_WITH`?

A simplified example of my tables partition and sort key looks like this:

```
PK    |SK
my_pk |2022-05-13T08:30:00Z#tag0
my_pk |2022-05-13T08:45:00Z#tag0
my_pk |2022-05-13T08:45:00Z#tag1
my_pk |2022-05-13T08:45:00Z#tag2
my_pk |2022-05-13T09:00:00Z#tag0
my_pk |2022-05-13T09:00:00Z#tag1
```

If my `SK` didn't include the `...#tag` postfix I could use a `KeyConditionExpression` like this:

```
"KeyConditionExpression": "#pk = :pk AND #sk BETWEEN :start AND :end"
```

where `start` and `end` are e.g. `2022-05-13T08:45:00Z` and `2022-05-13T09:00:00Z`, respectively, but I am unsure how to do it when the postfix is there.

Note: I never need to query with the `tag`, it's just there to ensure that the composite primary key is unique.

Note2: I am using python and boto3 to execute the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use between where `:end` = `2022-05-13T09:00:00Z$`. Dollar sign is the next value after hash in ASCII, so this will capture all values starting with `2022-05-13T09:00:00Z#`.

Comment: Can you please share a reference of this on AWS website. I was unable to find it.

Comment: @AnkushJain What specifically are you looking to find? The sorting of items for strings is [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html#Query.KeyConditionExpressions) quote: "Query results are always sorted by the sort key value. If the data type of the sort key is Number, the results are returned in numeric order. Otherwise, the results are returned in order of UTF-8 bytes. By default, the sort order is ascending."

Comment: Does it mean, this string (which is Date in ISO string) is converted into UTF-8 first, and then sorting is applied. So, I am confused, is it guaranteed that UTF-8 string and Date both will always have the same sort order?

Comment: @AnkushJain you said "UTF-8 string and Date both will always have the same sort order". There is no converting of types. All strings are saved as UTF-8. There is no Date type. `2022-05-13T09:00:00Z` is a string, not a Date. All string Sort Keys are saved in DynamoDB in lexicographical order.

Answer (score -1):

Partition and sort keys in a LSI or GSI do not need to be unique. So you can create an LSI, and use date column there as sort key.

This post exactly talks about this - [Local Secondary Indexes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LSI.html).

Here is an screenshot from that page.
[image]

> To ensure uniqueness in composite primary key, you can store some random string in `sort key` column.

Comment: you can use the between operator on string types.

Comment: @RossWilliams - Thanks for letting me know. I checked that we can use String data type to represent a date using ISO string.  I verified it on my AWS Console. And I have updated my answer as well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I am trying to do this without adding indexes.